# java - How to make Struts radio tag create a vertical list "The OGNL way"

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

This post has a reference to SO question"[How to make Struts radio tag create a vertical list of radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5809211/5086633)"
only difference is that I don't want to use an iterator.

I just want to do like this.

```
radio button
* abc
* xyz
```

I am using struts tag code like this:

```xml
<s:radio id="testing"
list="#{'val1':'abc','val2':'xyz'}" />
```

Please note that I don't want to use a list like this to iterate through the list elements. I'd like to enter those values manually as above.. More or less i just want a tweak like `"put a <br> element here and there"` to just make the next radio button `xyz` come to the next line and not be attached to `abc` in the same line. Hope this explanation makes more clear the solution I'm looking at.

```xml
<s:iterator value="aList"> 
    <s:radio key="selectedId" list="{aObject}" listKey="id" listValue="name"/><br/> 
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Read the answer from the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5809440/1700321.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making the options of a <s:checkboxlist> display vertically in struts2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422903/making-the-options-of-a-scheckboxlist-display-vertically-in-struts2)

Comment: Alek I dont want to used iterator tag ..<s:iterator value="myList"> 
    <s:radio key="selectedId" list="{myObject}" listKey="id" listValue="name"/><br/> 
</s:iterator> as i am manually writing thise two values

Comment: *as i am manually writing thise two values* - What? There are other options in linked questions. Read carefully.

Comment: You can use `#{'val1':'abc','val2':'xyz'}` inside `<s:iterator>`'s `value` also. :)

Comment: granted can that be done in the jsp itself and not to go to backend to fetch the data for vale?? possible. for me the list # is doing the trick.. without having to retrieve these constant values.

Comment: What? Just move `list` part from checkbox to iterator.

Comment: Alek I feels awkward pestering you again :)  u mean this <s:iterator value="#{'val1':'abc','val2':'xyz'}"> 
    <s:radio key="selectedId" list="#{'val1':'abc','val2':'xyz'}" listKey="id" listValue="name"/><br/> 
</s:iterator>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108615/discussion-between-aleksandr-m-and-yeppe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know that ognl created map can be used to do this...

**The Solution:**

```xml
<s:iterator value="#{'val1':'abc','val2':'xyz'}" var="some"> 
    <s:radio key="selectedId" list="#some" listKey="key" listValue="value"/><br/>
</s:iterator >
```

Comment: Just a small add on-->  adding this "listKey="key" listValue="value"" will give you the key part of the "key value pair" adjacent to the radio button.. otherwise, you may see something like this---> *val1=abc *val2=xyz