# Cannot get <s:checkboxlist> to display as a vertical list

Tags: java, html, css, struts2

I have reviewed [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422903/making-the-options-of-a-scheckboxlist-display-vertically-in-struts2) and I have tried to implement the CSS solution but without luck.

Is there a **CSS only** solution to the code I already have?

**JSP:**

```
<s:checkboxlist list="membersList" name="members" listKey="membersId" class = "checkBoxListItem"
                                listValue="membersFirstName" />
```

**CSS**

```
label[for*=members-]:after {
    content:"\A"; white-space:pre;
}
```

HTML generated by the label:

[image: generate html code for checkboxlist]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found a solution. It was really easy to be honest ! **I just changed the `display` property for the checkbox label**

```
[type="checkbox"]+label {
    display: block;
}
```

Now the checkboxes look like this

[image]

**Another way to achieve this is:**

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
    position: relative;
    left: -9999px;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}
```

Hope this helps people with the same issue!